# Class not found although it is properly referenced

Tags: php, symfony

I must be blind.  I cannot figure out why but I am getting an exception:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'BConway\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type\BusinessType' not found
```

Here are my files:

```
<?php

namespace BConway\WebsiteBundle\Controller;

use BConway\WebsiteBundle\Document\Business;
use BConway\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type\BusinessType;
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class BusinessController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $formBusiness = $this->createForm(new BusinessType(), new Business());
        $formBusiness->handleRequest($request);

        return $this->render('BConwayWebsiteBundle:Business:new.html.twig', array(
            'formBusiness' => $formBusiness->createView(),
            'action'       => 'create',
        ));
    }
}

<?php
// src/BConway/WebsiteBundle/Form/Type/BusinessType.php
namespace BConway\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use BConway\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type\AddressType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BusinessType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ad', 'string')
            ->add('address', new AddressType())
            ->add('claimed', 'boolean')
            ->add('coupons', 'string')
            ->add('dateCreated', 'date')
            ->add('dateModified', 'date')
//            ->add('hours', 'collection', array('type' => new HoursType()))
            ->add('name', 'string')
            ->add('organization', 'string')
            ->add('permanentlyClosed', 'string')
            ->add('phone', 'string')
//            ->add('services', 'collection', array('type', new ServiceType()))
            ->add('tags', 'collection')
            ->add('website', 'string');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BConway\WebsiteBundle\Document\Business',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'business';
    }
}
```

What am I not seeing?  I have been staring at these files for an hour and I cannot find the issue.

I apologize for this section but SO will not allow me to submit my question because too much of it is code versus text....so I am just filling up space.

Comment: Is your file system case sensitive?

Comment: Have you tried manually remove cache?

Comment: @LarsStrojny: Yes, Ubuntu...what do you see that would be a problem for case sensitivity?

Comment: The permissions of the file `BusinessType.php` is correct?

Comment: Yes.  This is my first project using DoctrineMongoDBBundle, I have used Doctrine with MySQL in the past.  I am wondering if somehow that is related.  I am doig everything exactly the same as I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the FormType.php file in MyBundle\Form, I missed creating the MyBundle\Form\Type folder.